# Name of a sliding spring connector for 18650 or similar cylindrical batteries

Tags: batteries, identification, connector

I'm looking for a generic name of a sliding spring style of connector for a battery (could be an 18650 type or some other cylindrical shape), used in products as shown in the picture below.
Searching for "sliding spring connector" and "universal battery holder" did not give any results for just the connector itself.

Is there a proper name for such a connector?

[image]

Comment: it's not the contact that slides

Comment: @jsotola Is that a hint?

Comment: it's an observation ... the contact is attached to a sliding component, so it's not a "sliding contact" per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no standard name for such a sliding component in a battery connector

So to find out more,
I've purchased and torn down a product with that sliding component.
As shown in the pictures below, it is nothing more than a spring that is soldered to a PCB board and connected to the battery contact by a hook.

From this teardown, my best guess is any sliding mechanism for the purpose of a battery connection has to be either custom-made or repurposed from other materials.

[image]

[image]